# NA values in filled.contour() contour plot

Tags: r

I'm using the filled.contour() function to make a contour plot.

This is my (simplified) R code:

```
testdata <- read.csv("test.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",",fill=TRUE)
x <- as.matrix(subset(testdata,select=X))
z <- as.matrix(subset(testdata,select=c(L1,L2,L3,L4)))
filled.contour(x=x,z=z,nlevels=20)
```

and this my (simplified) testing data:

```
X,L1,L2,L3,L4
10,5,5,5,2
25,3,5,5,2
30,3,3,5,2
45,3,3,2,2
```

My problem is: if the data contains NA values I get 'holes' in my plot. How can I handle this? Values should be interpolated. I can't find information about the function interpolation itself. So?

Comment: Whatever formula for interpolation you would write on a piece of paper is the same formula that you would create for R. ie. Linear? Polynomial? Spline?

Comment: R doesn't automagically replace NA values in a data set with interpolated information without you telling it WHAT and HOW to interpolate.

Comment: Okay. But how can I tell filled.contour() how to interpolate?

Comment: You don't. First you use the functions like: spline(), splinefun(), approxfun(), on your data, then you pump that data into filled.contour(). Take a look at the usage examples in all of the ? for those functions.

Comment: Thanks. I try to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a direct answer to your question, but here is a good start:

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/approxfun.html

Comment: So, first interpolation, then filled.contour() call. Thanks